# Why is my program saying Mir isn't working?

Tags: mir

I am trying to run the application BibleTime after compiling it myself and I keep getting this error:

```
Loading module: 'libubuntu_application_api_desktop_mirclient.so.3.0.0'
UbuntuClientIntegration: connection to Mir server failed. Check that a Mir server is
running, and the correct socket is being used and is accessible. The shell may have
rejected the incoming connection, so check its log file
```

I am not running Mir. I am running XFCE. Any ideas as to why I'm getting Mir related errors?